# Linux Computer Sharing Internet To Router Not Working

Tags: linux, networking, router, internet, ip

I have followed many guides out there on how to connect my linux desktop (using kde and network manager) to the wan of a router so as to share my wifi internet connection. I have 2 wifi cards. I have a mobo ethernet and a usb ethernet as well.

Current setup:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    
    altname enp9s0
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth3
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dfa0:b499:5011:7137/64 scope link noprefixroute 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    
    altname enp10s0u4
    inet 192.168.0.205/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth4
    valid_lft 5559sec preferred_lft 5559sec
    inet6 fe80::ca35:b706:3221:389a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan5: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
   
    altname wlp7s0
5: wlan3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    
    altname wlp8s0
    inet 192.168.1.130/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan3
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9b34:b8cc:c0d4:7e24/64 scope link noprefixroute 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
   
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So my eth3 is supplying the ip address for the router. and wlan3 and wlan5 is supplying internet. I have tried DHCP for the router WAN as well as STATIC with the following:

```
ip:               10.42.0.2
subnet:           255.255.255.0
default gateway:  10.42.0.1
dns:              10.42.0.1
```

Currently the router has a green symbol for internet and the web interface says internet is connected. I did this by creating a new connection, restricting to device eth3, and ipv4 method "shared to other computers".

So the router seems happy. But when I connect to the router from my phone I get an ip address 192.168.0.119 but with no internet ( its a samsung s20 and asks me if I want to connect since there is no internet connection, and I say yes, just this one time)

When I use IP Tools on my phone and do a traceroute to google.com it shows 192.168.0.1 then 10.42.0.1 then it stops.

I have added iptables commands as well as the kernel option for ipv4 packet forwarding. Nothing gets my phone to the internet through my router.

I wouldn't mind some step by step process on how to view the packets and see what the ip headers are and what they should be. I feel like everyone glosses over these details and just tell people solutions that aren't easily troubleshooted.

if you want to see my iptables:

```
root: ~> iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  10.42.0.0/24         anywhere            
LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  10.42.0.0/24         anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootpc
```

**EDIT:**
@Peregrino69   The reason I don't want to interface with the "normal" router is a matter of speed.  I'm using a VR virtual machine(gpu passthrough) setup and need my own router connected directly to my computer so that when I connect my quest 2 to the router I will get the appropriate speeds with virtual desktop as well as skybox (movies).  But I also want internet connectivity when I connect my quest 2 to my own router.  Also, and this may not be respected as much, I need knowledge about such things.  I'm not purely interested in getting it working.  I need to know why it works or doesn't work.

**EDIT 3**
here is my latest info:
current setup was updated

eth3 is connected from my computer to wan with a network manager connection "shared to other computers"

the router has no NAT stuff that I can see.  It is a TP Link.  You can see what I have here: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07N1L5HX1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N1L5HX1)

it has UPnP enabled but nothing is displayed on that page.

[image: routing on router]
wlan3 is connected from my wifi card to router LAN 192.168.1.0/24
I had wlan3 setup with /23 instead of /24 because I was trying to get it on the same network as anything connected to my connected router.  that is another issue.  I just connected wlan3 via /24
I've disconnected wlan5 and eth4 for the present time

sysctl:

```
root: ~> sysctl net.ipv4
...
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
...
net.ipv4.conf.eth3.forwarding = 1
...
```

latest iptables:

```
root: ~> iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Mar 31 01:37:38 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [145211:42812440]
:INPUT ACCEPT [8987:591413]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13293:5054949]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [12459:4884182]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth3 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar 31 01:37:38 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Mar 31 01:37:38 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1157190:19678443094]
:INPUT ACCEPT [948790:19513179556]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [162522:148255068]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [867963:19370366770]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1015528:19517495487]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar 31 01:37:38 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Mar 31 01:37:38 2023
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1686243:20749169464]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1182929:19427208163]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar 31 01:37:38 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Mar 31 01:37:38 2023
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [1266254:20518815090]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [168441:148709755]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1182929:19427208163]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar 31 01:37:38 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Mar 31 01:37:38 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [944745:19512471228]
:FORWARD DROP [15759:1324771]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [867947:19370361522]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar 31 01:37:38 2023
```

tcpdumps while doing a traceroute on phone to 13.112.187.226 which is w3schools.org.  just wanted a simple web page to access:

eth3:

```
root: ~> tcpdump -i eth3 -n udp -w ./eth3.txt
tcpdump: listening on eth3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
^C35 packets captured
37 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel


root: ~> tcpdump -r ./eth3.txt 
reading from file ./eth3.txt, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144
02:06:40.146709 IP 10.42.0.2.60589 > 10.42.0.1.domain: 2+ A? a.root-servers.net. (36)
02:06:40.146910 IP 10.42.0.1.domain > 10.42.0.2.60589: 2 1/0/0 A 198.41.0.4 (52)
02:06:40.859784 IP 10.42.0.2.canditv > 10.42.0.1.domain: 29431+ A? probes.probelytics.com. (40)
02:06:40.860235 IP 10.42.0.2.38287 > 10.42.0.1.domain: 14888+ A? probes.probelytics.com. (40)
02:06:42.219228 IP 10.42.0.2.40567 > 10.42.0.1.domain: 31+ A? time-b.nist.gov. (33)
02:06:42.219764 IP 10.42.0.2.48973 > 10.42.0.1.domain: 5494+ A? time-b.nist.gov. (33)
02:06:42.219764 IP 10.42.0.2.43738 > 10.42.0.1.domain: 31+ A? time-b.nist.gov. (33)
02:06:43.172699 IP 10.42.0.2.39751 > 10.42.0.1.domain: 58256+ A? live.com. (26)
02:06:43.172878 IP 10.42.0.1.domain > 10.42.0.2.39751: 58256 1/0/0 A 204.79.197.212 (42)
02:06:45.865474 IP 10.42.0.2.canditv > 10.42.0.1.domain: 29431+ A? probes.probelytics.com. (40)
02:06:45.897767 IP 10.42.0.1.domain > 10.42.0.2.canditv: 29431 2/2/12 A 172.67.147.19, A 104.21.10.243 (391)
02:06:45.897784 IP 10.42.0.1.domain > 10.42.0.2.38287: 14888 2/2/12 A 172.67.147.19, A 104.21.10.243 (391)
02:06:47.219375 IP 10.42.0.2.43248 > used-to-be-ntp.okstate.edu.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:47.219716 IP 10.42.0.2.52038 > used-to-be-ntp.okstate.edu.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:47.452265 IP 10.42.0.2.27341 > 10.42.0.1.domain: 25678+ A? mtalk.google.com. (34)
02:06:47.452819 IP 10.42.0.2.53748 > 10.42.0.1.domain: 16638+ A? mtalk.google.com. (34)
02:06:47.719848 IP 10.42.0.2.45868 > time-nw.nist.gov.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:47.720384 IP 10.42.0.2.58488 > time-nw.nist.gov.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:48.220686 IP 10.42.0.2.49532 > ntp.alaska.edu.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:48.221193 IP 10.42.0.2.54813 > ntp.alaska.edu.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:48.721475 IP 10.42.0.2.47223 > 140.142.16.34.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:48.721475 IP 10.42.0.2.34965 > 140.142.16.34.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:49.221840 IP 10.42.0.2.56956 > india.colorado.edu.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:49.221989 IP 10.42.0.2.34474 > india.colorado.edu.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:49.722792 IP 10.42.0.2.55790 > 137.146.210.250.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:49.722792 IP 10.42.0.2.46281 > 137.146.210.250.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:50.223511 IP 10.42.0.2.37790 > sth1.ntp.se.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:50.223693 IP 10.42.0.2.56904 > sth1.ntp.se.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:50.724017 IP 10.42.0.2.53096 > tick.uh.edu.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:50.724017 IP 10.42.0.2.40899 > tick.uh.edu.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:51.224758 IP 10.42.0.2.57519 > this.has.not.been.ntp.server.time.nist.gov.since.2012.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:51.224946 IP 10.42.0.2.39152 > this.has.not.been.ntp.server.time.nist.gov.since.2012.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:51.617033 IP 10.42.0.1.59824 > 239.255.255.250.ssdp: UDP, length 173
02:06:51.725581 IP 10.42.0.2.44994 > a4.cs.umb.edu.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
02:06:51.725582 IP 10.42.0.2.50268 > a4.cs.umb.edu.ntp: NTPv3, Client, length 48
```

wlan3:

```
root: ~> tcpdump -i wlan3 -n udp -w ./wlan3.txt
tcpdump: listening on wlan3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
^C4 packets captured
5 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

root: ~> tcpdump -r ./wlan3.txt 
reading from file ./wlan3.txt, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144
02:05:32.164673 IP DESKTOP-89BBSOL.db-lsp-disc > 255.255.255.255.db-lsp-disc: UDP, length 180
02:05:34.213746 IP 192.168.1.130.54474 > DeviceDHCP.Home.domain: 48304+ A? firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com. (54)
02:05:34.226650 IP DeviceDHCP.Home.domain > 192.168.1.130.54474: 48304 9/4/8 A 172.253.124.95, A 142.250.105.95, A 142.250.9.95, A 142.250.189.106, A 74.125.138.95, A 64.233.185.95, A 64.233.177.95, A 142.250.176.74, A 142.251.45.234 (456)
02:05:35.747694 IP ESP_DCE2AA.49154 > 255.255.255.255.6667: UDP, length 188
```

Comment: Have you added masquerading on the way out? Can you share your `iptables -t nat -L` (there you need an entry for masquerading, otherwise outgoing packets will go out with source `10.42.0.2` which the upstream router will not know how to reach to send the replies back.

Comment: @Peregrino69 just answered your questions with an EDIT to my question.  Thanks for engaging.

Comment: @gepa just answered your question with an EDIT to my question.  Thanks for engaging.

Comment: I think you should just *replace* the iptables outputs with the output of `iptables-save`. Besides, double check the ipv4 forwarding sysctls (including the interface specific ones, perhaps).

Comment: @Tom Yan  I understand iptables-save as just dumping what is already there.  How does replacing with iptables-save output help?   Maybe more condensed,no repeats?

Comment: I don't remember the exact pitfall of `iptables -L` but you can take a look at what `iptables-save` print. The bottom line is that it shows everything in a much clearer way without giving any garbage.

Comment: @TomYan  sorry I misread what you wanted me to do.  I posted the output of iptables-save and double checked `sysctl net.ipv4`

Comment: In the new `iptables-save` output I don't see you allowing forwarding (but it was in your original `iptables -L` output, so I guess you just forgot to add it back after the reboot. Apart from that, the masquerading you need to do for packets outgoing from your wan interface (I assume this is `eth4`?). Again, in the previous `iptables -L` you seemed to have a very generic masquerading for all outgoing packets, so this is probably not the issue either. Can you share how is your router configured, it obviously gives DHCP to your phone, but does it NAT/masquerade on the way to your server?

Comment: One thing you can try for debugging it, is running `tcpdump -i eth3 -n udp or icmp` and `tcpdump -i eth4 udp or icmp` while you are doing the traceroute from your phone. You should see what packets come in from eth3 and if they are getting remapped and sent out correctly on eth4, and whether you are getting replies from eth4 and getting them back to eth3. Doing this you can localize where the chain of events (eth3-send, eth4-send, eth4-response, eth3-response) breaks (at least the first step is probably happening, since you see 10.42.0.1 in your traceroute output).

Comment: @gepa AFAIR you can't do `-i` match in the nat table, but only `-s` or `-o` (for the latter it should be a wireless NIC if I have read correctly?)

Comment: @TomYan I meant this from OP: `iptables -t nat -A POSTPROCESSING -o eth3 -j MASQUERADE` should be like this `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth4 -j MASQUERADE` (I guess the POSTPROCESSING was just a typo). So I still meant `-o`, but for packets outgoing to `eth4` instead. My understanding is that this is the wan interface, where the packets go out through, `eth3` is the internal one where the packets coming from the router arrive.

Comment: I think he wants to use a wireless NIC as the "upstream". `share my wifi internet connection` / `wlan3 and wlan5 is supplying internet`.

Comment: You seem to be right, I didn't notice this detail earlier. In this case, replace `eth4` by `wlan3` and/or `wlan5` in my comments. I was mainly referring to whichever interface is the upstream one.

Comment: @TomYan  I appreciate the continued support.  I just updated stuff with EDIT 3

Comment: @gepa I appreciate the continued support.  I just updated stuff with EDIT 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it working now...I mean I'm able to access the internet.  I would like an explanation of why this works.  I will dig a little myself and try to update answer.

But this is what worked for me:

eth3 is mobo ethernet link to wan of router with method "shared to other computers"

wlan3 is wifi card to 192.168.1.0/24 router providing internet to computer

phone is connecting to router within 192.168.0.1 network

router has static IP as listed in the question.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth3 -o wlan3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan3 -o eth3 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan3 -j MASQUERADE
```

as far as I can tell all of my iptables were messed up concerning this connection, but the one that was really necessary was the 2nd iptables.  I mean that one wasn't part of some of the tutorials I looked at.

Comment: Short explanation why you need the MASQUERADE rule (the FORWARD rules should be obvious). When a packet arrives through eth3, it has source-IP `10.42.0.2` (this is from the router NAT that does the first masquerading), and destination IP some public IP, e.g. `8.8.8.8`.  The routing figures out it has to send the packet over wlan3, but doesn't do any translation, so the packet goes out as is `10.42.0.2->8.8.8.8`. Masquerading tells (postrouting, after the routing decision is made), to replace the source by the local IP, `10.42.0.1` (and keep track of it, so return packets get translated back).